# CLion debugging using Makefile [UNIX]

Tags: ubuntu, debugging, makefile, compilation, clion

currently I'm using CLion on my ubuntu and I've followed the steps to be able to use Makefile with CLion, to autocompile on Makefile change and so... https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/managing-makefile-projects.html

Everything is working as it should, but I can't use the clion debugging now
Is there any way to debug using Makefile or is it only possible with cmakelists?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/custom-build-targets.html).

The process involves creating a 'Custom Build Application', with 'Custom Build Target' and custom 'External Tools' - but it is rather quick and painless. The examples in the doc pertain specifically to make.